# Can't step into a function in a shared library using Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt

I've researched this in Stack Overflow and have not been able to find anyone who has addressed my exact problem.  I have built a shared library, using Autotools, in Ubuntu using Eclipse CDT.  I am using this library in a debug executable using CUnit. When I call a function in the shared library, I can't step into it.  However, if I set a breakpoint in the shared library code, the executable will stop at the breakpoint and I can debug the library code.  Any ideas on how I can actually step into the function so I don't have to set a breakpoint in the shared library code.

Thanks!!